# Traversing Scheme function as a list

Tags: reflection, lisp, scheme, metaprogramming, homoiconicity

Isn't it possible to treat functions in Scheme as any other list?

Basically, what I want do to is something like this:

```
(define (foo) "hello")

(cdr foo)  ; or similar, should return the list ((foo) "hello")
```

I've found [a similar discussion](http://www.a-chinaman.com/2008/05/26/reflection-in-scheme/) about this, and I feel a bit disappointed if this is not possible with Scheme.  If so, *why* is this impossible?  Is it possible in other lisps?

EDIT:  Changed (cdr 'foo) to (cdr foo) -- it was misleading.  I'm asking, *why* can't I access a function as a list?

Comment: Also found some interesting notes: http://www.cs.brown.edu/pipermail/plt-scheme/2006-May/013052.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have often wanted to be able to do the same thing csl.
Below is a quick example of how you could go about doing this in mzscheme.

DrScheme 4.2

```
(module qdefine mzscheme
  (provide ;(all-from-except mzscheme let)
   (rename define olddefine)
   (rename quote-define define)
   (rename quote-cdr cdr)
   (rename quote-car car))

  (define define-list '())
  (define define-list-add 
    (lambda (key value)
      (set! define-list (cons `(,key ,value) define-list))))

  (define-syntax quote-define
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((_ (pro-name args ...) body ...) 
       (begin
         (define (pro-name args ...) body ...)
         (define-list-add pro-name  '((pro-name args ...) body ...))))
      ((_ pro-name pro) (begin
                          (define pro-name pro)
                          (define-list-add pro-name 'pro)))

      ))

  (define quote-cdr (lambda (lst)
                      (if (procedure? lst)
                          (cdr (cadr (assoc lst define-list)))
                          (cdr lst))))

  (define quote-car (lambda (lst)
                      (if (procedure? lst)
                          (car (cadr (assoc lst define-list)))
                          (car lst))))
  )
(require 'qdefine)

(define testfunc (lambda (args) args))
(cdr testfunc)
(car testfunc)

(define (testfunc2 test) 'blah)
(cdr testfunc2)
(car testfunc2)

(define testlist '(1 2 3 4 5 6 'a))
(cdr testlist)
(car testlist)
```

Outputs:

```
((args) args)
lambda
('blah)
(testfunc2 test)
(2 3 4 5 6 'a)
1
>
```

Comment: Anyone know how to do it in other scheme implementations?

Comment: Depending on implementation I think you can do something similar with defmacro or Syntatic closures. I would like to have the macro equivalent of (define blah (lambda ...))(define blah (lambda (...) new code (blah ...))), but I have not found a scheme implementation that allows for a straight forward way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Your `define` form is not a function but a function definition.  In fact, it is a shorthand for

```
(define foo
  (lambda ()
    "hello"))
```

`Lambda` can be thought of as a "compiler invocation".  In this case, it produces a function which returns that string.  `Define` then binds this function to the symbol `'foo`.

Compare this to

```
(define foo "hello")
```

which binds just the string to the symbol `'foo`.  What would `(cdr foo)` return?

Now, it is imaginable that some Scheme implementation actually saves or has the option to save the `lambda` form when binding a function to a symbol.  You will have to check the documentation, but the kind of pure interpretation this implies surely would have an impact on performance.

*If* you manage to get this, though, it will return the `lambda` form, not the `define` form.

Comment: Excellent explanation!  Wouldn't it be possible to create my own define-form that both compiled the code (through eval) and kept the source around?  That would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

MIT Scheme has the ability to do this. (If you really want, comment on this and I'll give you the code. I had to find some undocumented functions to make it happen.)

However, it's not in the Scheme language definition, so implementations don't have to allow it. The reason for this is that in order to make functions faster, a good Scheme implementation will modify the functions. This means both rewriting them in a different language (either machine code or something fairly low-level) and taking out any bits you don't need - for instance, the `+` function must in general check whether its arguments are numbers, and if so, what sort of numbers, but if your function is a loop which calls `+`, you can just check once at the beginning, and make the function a lot faster.

Of course, you could still keep the lists around without too much trouble, even with all of these things. But if you tried to *modify* the lists, how would it work?

(Again, you could make it work. It would just be more work for implementers, and since it's not usually used in programs, most people probably just don't want to bother.)

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to get the code.  Maybe post it online (gist/pastebin) ?

Comment: I'm sorry - I thought I had it, but I just looked and I couldn't find it. I made it by basically downloading the mit-scheme sources, finding how they represented interpreted procedures, and using a few of the functions in that file which happened to be available at the REPL, even though they probably shouldn't have been.

Answer (score 2):

In guile,

> guile> (define (foo bar) 'baz)
>   guile> (procedure-source foo)
>    (lambda (bar) (quote baz))
>   guile> (cdr (procedure-source foo))
>    ((bar) (quote baz))
>   guile>

Answer (score 1):

'foo evaluates to a symbol, you can't take the CDR of a symbol.

What you may want to do is (cdr foo), but this does not work. The value of a FOO is a procedure, not a list.

Comment: Yeah; I'm asking _why_ I can't cdr a procedure.

Comment: because the procedure is not a list. You can cdr only lists. the procedure could be a bunch of machine instructions.

Comment: That's not a very satisfying answer -- you could say the same for lists, because you don't really know how lists are represented in memory.

Comment: @csl: CDR is defined for conses and lists. Nothing more. So CDR works for lists. Since a procedure is not a list, it won't work. A procedure is something else.

Answer (score 1):

You **might** be able to access the function as a list using `pp` or `pretty-print`.  That said, you might also need to run your code in debug mode.   This is very implementation dependent however. I know it can work in Gambit-C.

Answer (score 1):

`(define (foo) ...)` produces a compiled object, and it's a *value* - a *procedure*.
You cannot iterate over it because it is not an *s-expression*.

Like what other suggested, you should check out your programming environment and see
if it has any facilities for such tasks.